# Encrypting and Signing with Web Crypto API

Tags: encryption, webcrypto-api

I am working on a web-based application where I would like to use public key cryptography in my user collaboration. I'm interested in taking advantage of the [Web Crypto API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Crypto_API) for this purpose.

I believe it's standard practice to not actually encrypt data with asymmetric encryption but instead generate a symmetric key to do the encryption then just use the asymmetric key to secure that symmetric key. The [`wrapKey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/wrapKey) method seems perfect for this as I can generate a symmetric key then wrap it with the collaborator's public key.

The only asymmetric algorithm supported for wrapping a key (or encryption in general) in the Web Crypto API is `RSA-OAEP`. That means I likely want my asymmetric keys to use that algorithm.

At the same time I also want to be able to sign and verify certain messages between collaborators. The most obvious thing to me is to use the same asymmetric keys I'm already using for this symmetric key exchange for signing and verification. But when I look at the [sign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/sign) API the `RSA-OAEP` is not a support algorithm. If fact there doesn't seem to be any overlap between the algorithms I can choose for encryption vs signatures.

Does this means when doing key exchange I really need to have two different public keys I need to exchange for collaboration? One for encryption (indirectly via `wrapKey`) and one for signatures? Or am I missing some obvious way to have a single public/private key that can do both encryption and signatures with the Web Crypto API?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34573629/webcrypto-api-algorithm-to-encrypt-decrypt-and-also-sign-verify) seems related although not exactly the same. That message is talking about the integrity of the encrypted payload I believe. What I am interested in doing is verifying the creator of some content.

Comment: For security reasons, different key pairs for signing and encryption are recommended, s. [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/12090). However, most libraries *technically* allow one key pair to be used for multiple purposes. The WebCrypto API makes such an approach more difficult by binding the algorithm to the `CryptoKey` object, so that encryption (e.g. `RSA-OAEP`) and signing (e.g. `RSA-PSS`) are mutually exclusive *per* `CryptoKey` object. This can of course be circumvented by importing the same key into two different `CryptoKey` objects, one for encryption and one for signing.

Comment: Sounds like it may be possible but it's not recommended per the article you linked. I guess I'm just used to something like GPG where I generate a key and then can indicate it is for specific purposes (encryption, signing, authentication). I'd be happy to mark your comment as the correct answer although I don't know how to promote a comment to an answer. Feel free to create it as an answer and I'll mark it as correct so you get the points. Thanks!